# Under review for things outside my control. Should I stay or should I go?

Tags: project-management, performance-reviews

I came up with a much longer version of this but here is the skinny:

As a new employee, I was tasked to create an application.  I did all my core work on time but the underlying database architecture was not up to the job and causing major delays.

To have something to show, I created a proof of concept using a different database architecture, which worked fine, but management was adamant I use their solution and unhappy the project was slipping.

I created a second demo using the "correct" architecture, which everybody promptly hated because it was very slow and sometimes failed due to a vendor bug.

I was then written up and given six months to "turn things around".  To help with the database architecture, the company assigned a team of data engineers to fix the problem.  They are still at it four months later while the project languishes.  Vendor still hasn't fixed the bug.

I have been working on other things in the meantime and haven't missed any deadlines, but I was told I have two months to "improve", although the definition of improvement is totally nonspecific, consisting of "better collaboration", "better understanding" and "better enthusiasm".

My gut tells me they need to throw somebody under the bus to appease management and a relatively new employee probably fits the bill.  I also get the impression that if somebody says you need to improve but can't really say exactly what it is you need to improve, you are probably already done for.   Should I bail now while I still have a job or wait and see if maybe this will all blow over?

Comment: Why would you wait? Do you actually want to work at a company that has treated you this way?

Comment: Do you understand what you did wrong yet and why it was a very bad mistake? You cannot ever willy nilly replace a backend database without a great deal of discussion and official permission even for a demo. You did double the work. Instead you should have documented the issues  and suggested ways to refactor it to get to where you needed to be. Likely other applications were dependent on this data in this database and to just decide not to use it because you were having trouble making it work was a huge mistake and one that would have gotten you fired pretty much anywhere I ever worked.

Comment: "underlying database architecture was not up to the job"  What the heck?   **Every** "underlying database architecture", ever, in the history of computing, has been crap.  Note that the two alternates you tried were also total crap.  It's amazing they let you waste time fooling around on those experiments.  For goodness sake, just do it using the backend given.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely you'll actually get fired.  All software is an utter shambles.  Just enjoy and press on.  Simply get it working with the current system.  You'll never, ever, encounter a "good" backend.

Comment: @HLGEM has the right answer here. "I was tasked to create an application. I did all my core work on time but the underlying database architecture was not up to the job and causing major delays." - the last two sentences are contradictory. Unless you are strictly a front end dev, the backend of an app is important too. If it wasn't up to snuff, then you did not complete the core work if the requirement was a functional system. If your second attempt was still a failure they seem justified in being a little frustrated

Comment: @Fattie Really, every "underlying database architecture", ever, in the history of computing had been crap.  Your comments are crap.

Comment: @Fattie To add a little more to some of the comments, the database architecture didn't support the ad-hoc query capability needed to meet the requirements, period.  I understand there are memory limitations and other constraints, but in this case the database couldn't pull a single record for any given ad-hoc query.  That is the definition of crap.  I get slow, I get all kinds of limitations, but if you can't pull data at all, you got crap.  It's a long story but the design was built to support extremely fast ingest, but nobody considered what to do when somebody wanted to get data back out.

Comment: @HLGEM I was not tasked to work on the backend, only to develop a prototype to analyze and display the data in an interactive format.  The backend would not deliver the data interactively so I dumped the data to a database that would.  That was four months ago.  So that choice was have a demo working off a non-sanctioned database or no demo at all.  I didn't do double work, I only moved the data to a platform that would support the POC.  There is no contradiction here.

Comment: Hi @kmccarty dude.  The first **hour** you were given this task, why didn't you just state "Oh, the database doesn't have ad-hoc query capability - what should I do?"  Why didn't you do that?  Trying to grasp the situation here.

Comment: @Fattie It wasn't like they said, "Oh by the way, you can't run ad-hoc queries".  Frankly I didn't believe that was actually possible by definition.  I know Hive somewhat and still can't believe they mucked it up so bad.  Besides, everybody led me to believe it would be fine but nobody before me had actually tried.  They just assumed it would work.  Only after the experts said it required a complete rework did anybody take what I said seriously.

Comment: @Fattie - This gets even better.  My boss just called me in to say he wants me to kludge something together, again, just so we have something to show some customers.  It won't use the proposed architecture of course, or work, but he wants to see pretty plots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typical of a sick company.

Update your resume, get out.  They don't want a working solution, they don't want to listen to reason, they've got a dog and they know it.  They want someone to blame, and you are it.

Basically, you need to keep things running as best as you can while you job hunt.  You are the proverbial sacrificial lamb.

Comment: Just an update, the company replaced some of the original architecture team but seem to have "forgiven" me for not making this work.  Nine months later my kludge is still the only working option, but they hired a team of four data engineers to work on a solution and I expect they will figure it out eventually, but I am taking your advice and heading outta here.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely bail. Job hunting is slow and having a steady income relieves much of the stress. Not to mention you have more bargaining power when negotiating salaries, since you can legitimately say you do not need the job you're applying for.

Turning the question around on you.. Why would you stay? Do you want to work at a company that put a new hire in this situation? Do you trust them with your future? I think the answer in this case is obvious, unless you have further input?